# Iterating over Guice multibinder list

Tags: java, guice

Hi I am trying to construct list as following in module, which I can inject later into any class and use in the same module as follows:

```
public class MyConfigModule extends AbstractModule{

@Override
protected void configure() {
    Multibinder<String> myList =
            Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(), String.class, Names.named("MyList"));

    myList.addBinding().toInstance("Test1");

    MapBinder<String, IManager> myMap = MapBinder
            .newMapBinder(binder(), String.class, IManager.class, 
                          Names.named("ManagerMap"));

    for(each item in the above myList) <--- cannot figure out how to do this i.e. iterating over a multibinder

         myMap
            .addBinding(item).to(MyManager.class).asEagerSingleton();

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Short and disappointing answer is: you can't. If you look at the source code of [Multibinder](https://github.com/google/guice/blob/master/core/src/com/google/inject/multibindings/Multibinder.java), you see that it just delegates calls to an instance of [RealMultibinder](https://github.com/google/guice/blob/master/core/src/com/google/inject/internal/RealMultibinder.java). Unfortunately, `Multibinder` does not expose any method that would allow you to access the internal data of `RealMultibinder`. And even if it would, it wouldn't help since `RealMultibinder` however uses an implementation of [Binder](https://github.com/google/guice/blob/master/core/src/com/google/inject/Binder.java) to manage bindings. I could go on, but I think you get my point ;)

So the only option (and I really would not recommend that) is to reflect yourself through all those classes until you get to the data structure that is holing your bindings.